# Can I save local disk database inside flutter app? Where does documentsDirectory make path?

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to make a quiz application with flutter.

I made a sample_quiz.db with DB Browser for SQLite.

I want to save my database that is in my local disk(C) inside a flutter app.
I am never able to find the path.
(I installed both path_provider and path dependencies)

What I found is only for making a new database with CRUD in class DB_helper.dart.
But the CRUD isn't helpful because I don't need to Create or Delete data with phone.
I want to save my own data inside the app so that every person who downloads my quiz app can see the same data.

I thought it might be somewhere in lib or a new dart file.
I try to find where `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, but there is only the path inside an emulator.

Is there no way to save the database inside the code file?
How to upload, save and read my data in flutter app/ not emulator?

Please help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a folder inside your flutter project for example `assets`
copy your database inside this folder

and in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
   assets:
     - assets/sample_quiz.db
```

and now you have access to your database

Answer (score 0):

You can pack the database into an extra "assets" folder (on the same level as directory) and access it through your code (means parsing the data).